# CURL Python Issue When Hitting an API

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, request

The API I want to access is having me use CURL, something I'm unfamiliar with. I'm on windows using pycharm/spyder IDE (I can use both).

I've only used the library requests so not sure how to proceed. I tried the approach below using requests but got the error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable." I researched answers here but couldn't find a resolution.

What the API documentation says:

```
    $ curl -H "X-ABCD-Key: api_key" \
    https://api.abcd.com/searches.json
```

My approach:

```
    import requests
    url = "https://api.abcd.com/searches.json"
    auth = ("api_key")
    r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
    print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
import requests
headers = {'X-ABCD-Key': 'api_key'}
response = requests.get('https://api.abcd.com/searches.json', headers=headers)
```